# Codeigniter display TYPE_LABLE from TYPE table if result equal to specific CATEGORY

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent, codeigniter-3, eloquent-relationship

I'm working on Codeigniter rest API project and came across a problem. I would like my model to select additional data by condition.

if CATEGORY equals $CATEGORY show TYPE.TYPE_LABLE
otherwise just don't show "TYPE.TYPE_LABLE"

so how can i get this result?
thank you for your help.

```
    function get_data() {
        
        
        $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
        $CATEGORY = array('CATEGORY1', 'CATEGORY2', 'CATEGORY3', 'CATEGORY4');
        
        $types = array('type_1', 'type_2');
        if ($id != null) {
            $this->db->where('ID',$id);
//selct TYPE.TYPE_LABLE if CATEGORY equals $CATEGORY 
            $this->db->select('POST.ID, POST.DATE, TYPE.Post_Type as P_TYPE, TYPE.TYPE_LABLE$CATEGORY', FALSE);
            $this->db->join('TYPE', 'POST.TYPE_ID = TYPE.ID', 'left');
            $this->db->join('CATEGORY', 'POST.CATEGORY_ID = CATEGORY.ID', 'left');
            $this->db->order_by('POST.ID', 'DESC');
            $this->db->where_in('POST.Post_Type', $types);
            $this->db->where('POST.DATE >', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01-01-2019')) );
            $this->db->from('POST');
    
            $result = $this->db->get();
        } 
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: `otherwise just don't show the field` is not possible in SQL, all empty labels will return null values

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent to answer my question, I think I respected the way I should ask my question, I explained what I wanted, I put my code and the problematic .

Comment: Mr @mickmackusa i have edited my question

Comment: We cannot see your sample input and your desired output from your sample input.  This is why a db fiddle demo is the best way to receive high quality answers quickly.  By doing all of the "setup" for volunteers, you make your question much more attractive and volunteers don't have to waste their time setting up a fake database to test their advice.